# How can I control an input of a Siemens PLC with a 4N25 optocoupler?

Tags: opto-isolator, plc

I need to turn on/off an input of a Siemens PLC controlled by an external output of another machine.

I used an [optocoupler](https://www.vishay.com/docs/83725/4n25.pdf) because I need to isolate both circuits.

I have not been able to make this work. Can someone please tell me what am I doing wrong?

[image: Current electric diagram]

Comment: Are both +24V the same supply? Do the external machine and the PLC share GND?

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not very informative. What voltages exactly are you seeing at the PLC input and across the optocoupler LED?

Comment: What is the "1M" connection on port DIa?

Comment: @SimonFitch  https://support.industry.siemens.com/forum/ww/en/posts/how-to-connect-1m-pin-with-other-digital-inputs/190333

Answer (score 4):

Wire it as shown below.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2foDop6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Two options for external wiring.*

With your circuit the input is fed from a 2.2 kΩ source. This would limit the current at 24 V to about 10 mA. The problem is that there will be a similar sized resistor already on the PLC input to limit the current to the internal opto-isolator to 10 mA or so. The result of your resistor is to reduce the input current to a max of about 5 mA which may not be enough to turn the input on. You can confirm this theory by measuring the input voltage at I0 when your source signal is on and off.

This circuit will give a logic '1' on the PLC input when SW1 or SW2 is closed.

[image]

*Figure 2. For industrial applications DIN rail 24 V opto-couplers are available. These will be much more robust than a home-made opto-isolator version.*

Tip: Always assign designators to components. 'R2' is much simpler and more definite than 'the 2k2 resistor on the right above the transistor'.

Answer (score 3):

Your pullup on the PLC side is very low. CTR of the 4N25 can be as low as 20% and you need to add significant safety margin to account for aging etc. You are putting 11mA through the LED which is about as much as you should for decent life.

Assuming [this](https://support.industry.siemens.com/cs/document/107623221/simatic-s7-s7-1200-programmable-controller?dti=0&lc=en-DK) is the appropriate manual, the specification (page 1169) is as follows:

[image]

So you can simply put the optotransistor in series with the 24V to an input. The logic will be reversed from your example. However the 4N25 still has too low CTR for this to reliably work. I suggest replacing it with a [PC817](https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/73758.pdf) rank 'D' (rank 'D' is important) and then you can double the input resistor to (say) 4.7K and still have margin for aging and temperature (and the aging will be reduced because of the lower current and because that manufacturer has good quality LEDs).

Answer (score 0):

Note that forward current input should be 60 mA max, so R=24/0.060=400 Ohm for input and 50 mA max, at the output ... 24/0.050= 480 Ohm at the output.

Taking half current values leads to ~ 800 Ohm and ~ 1000 Ohm.

**Sometimes, one needs also a resistor (1k .. 10k) between pin 6 (base) to pin 4 (emitter).**

Note also that there is now an "inverting" function ...

Answer (score 0):

Here's an extract from Siemens S7 - 1200 PLC system manual.

[image]

The nominal input voltage is 24 V DC at 4 mA.

The minimum input voltage for logic '1' being 15 V DC at 2.5 mA, the value of the pull-up resistor should be not greater than (24 - 15) / 2.5 = 3.6 kΩ.

The maximum voltage for logic '0' being 5 V DC at 1 mA, the permissible voltage drop across the optocoupler output should be far lesser than 5 V. That would mean an optocoupler with a high CTR and LED current close to 5 mA.

It would be convenient to use a DIN rail mounted 24 V DC electromagnetic / solid state relay.

A standard 24 V DC electromagnetic relay may also suffice.

[image]